# insert View into RelativeLayout's childerne Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, insert, constant-expression

I'm in need of inserting a view obj to the children array of a relativeLayout.
but the problem is that i don't know how i can do it so it's Relative To Parent. like i do when i added it, like shown below

```
layout.Children.Add(BoxView, Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                    return parent.Width / 10;
                }), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                    return parent.Height / 5;
                }), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                    return parent.Width - 2 * (parent.Width / 10);
                }), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                    return parent.Height / 2;
                }));
```

Do anyone know how this can be done?

as always, Thanks for your time.

Comment: Plz someone, Anyone?